# Access SQL Server Database in Phonegap Cordova App

Tags: android, ios, sql, cordova, phonegap

I'm building an Hybrid App using Cordova in Visual Studio 2017, and JavaScript.

I have a SQL Server Database hosted on Google Cloud Platform and I want to access the data of this database in my App.

Which is the best way to do this in a Phonegap Cordova App? I have no idea since I've never did this before.

Thanks for now.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's probably possible to access a sql database directly with some javascript magic, it's not safe. In this situation you will need your app to contact a web service which will communicate with you SQL tables to relay the information. Think of the web service as a "middle-man".

There are existing services out there, but it is also easy enough to create your own setup similarly to this: https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/03/28/populate-your-phonegap-app-with-data-from-an-external-server-db/